# Connecting a preamp to computer

Tags: wiring, microphone

I've made a single transistor preamp for an electret mic. The curcuit is like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fioNyt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
I want to use this on a computer. The mic input of the pc has a GND an a mic wire. Should I just connect the GND to GND and OUT to mic or sth else is needed?
Newbie here. Thank you

Comment: Why do you think you need a transistor buffer stage?

Comment: @Andyaka Found this on web. I dont know what you mean? Can you suggest sth better?

Comment: Many sound systems have an inbult pre-amplifier for electret microphones, check the sound mixer controls.

Comment: most pcs will accept a elecrtret microphone directly connected to the microphone socket.

Comment: @Jasen It's a pc and I've cheked the settings. Everything seems ok. I want a little amp and noise cancellation more than the pc itself.

Comment: An amp doesn't give noise cancellation. Please justify why you think you need the transistor amplifier.

Comment: @Andyaka I know this isn't the best place to ask but what should I do?

Comment: It's simple:  justify why you think you need the transistor amplifier.

Comment: I guess you have found that without the peamp one must stay quite near the mic to get silent speech well recorded. Right? What kind of noise is the problem? Hiss, ambient room noises, AC hum or what?

Comment: @user287001 Yeah you're right. I think its a hum.

Comment: Preamp can make less substantial only those noises which are born inside your recording computer. Poor mic, poor shielding of the mic and non-silent environment will not get any help. BTW hum is 50 or 60 Hz fully steady  sound caused by the stray fields of mains AC operated equipment.

Comment: @user287001 OK thanks for the info. If I want to test this circuit should I just connect it the way I described in the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect clean +5V DC supply between "+5V" and the GND. Connect "Out" to the hot wire of the audio input. Connect GND to the ground side of the audio input. "Clean" means "taken from a separate battery" or a carefully filtered voltage. C1 can do the filtering if you have say 500 Ohm resistor in series with the +5V wire.

Some common elementary precautions:

Do not expect your computer operating +5V is clean, it has much noise which can be heard as buzzes. Be sure that your computer's supply current doesn't go through any wire between your mic or preamp and the computer. It would cause more buzzes.